# How to Index over Filtered set of a model through elasticsearch_dsl 's Persistence API

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-models, elasticsearch-dsl

This is my code `documents.py` code

```
class Blog(Document):
    title = fields.TextField()
    date_posted = fields.DateField()
   
    class Index:
        name = "blog_index"
        settings = {"number_of_shards": 1, "number_of_replicas": 0}

    class Django:
        model = Blog
        fields = ['title','date_posted']
```

This is my `models.py` code

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    """
    Blog Model fields are defined here
    """

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

But I don't want to populate all of my objects of Blog, I only want to populate those objects who are getting passed with these filter

example filter =   `Blog.objects.filter(title__isnull=False).distinct()`